# Spring JDBC Unable to insert

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am new to SpringBoot and I am using SpringBoot with JDBC for making an API. The INSERT is not working properly, I had made ID Unique and AutoIncremeneted it. Before I was inserting the ID and it was causing no problems.I am using MySql as the database.

The JSON I am using in POST is:

```
{
    "name":"Name",
    "email":"namegmail.com",
    "dob":"2000-04-09",
    "age":21
}
```

I am getting this Error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-20T13:10:16.925+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
    "path": "/api/v1/NewStudent"
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/")
public class StudentController {

    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService service){
        this.studentService=service;
    }


    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getHome(){
        return "Hey Welcome to Home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/NewStudent")
    public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody StudentClass studentClass){
        studentService.addNewStudent(studentClass);
    }

    @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public StudentClass getStudentSearch(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId){

        return studentService.getStudentSelect(userId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/AllStudents")
    public List<StudentClass> getAllStudents(){

        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }


}
```

StudentDao

```
public class StudentDaoClass implements StudentDao{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate;
    private List<StudentClass> selectAll;

    @Override
    public int insert(StudentClass student) {

        String query="INSERT INTO Student(std_name,std_email,std_dob,std_age)" +
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        int res=this.jdbctemplate.update(query,student.getName(),student.getEmail(),student.getDob(),student.getId());
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public StudentClass selectStudent(Long id) {

        String query="SELECT * FROM Student WHERE std_id=?";
        RowMapper<StudentClass> rowMapper=new RowMapperClass();
        StudentClass studentClass=this.jdbctemplate.queryForObject(query,rowMapper,id);

        return studentClass;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StudentClass> selectAllStudents() {

        String query="SELECT * FROM Student";
        selectAll=this.jdbctemplate.query(query,new RowMapperClass());
        return selectAll;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbctemplate() {
        return jdbctemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbctemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate) {
        this.jdbctemplate = jdbctemplate;
    }
}
```

StudentClass

```
public class StudentClass {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private Integer age;
    private String email;

    public StudentClass() {
    }

    public StudentClass(String name, String email,LocalDate dob ,Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentClass{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you properly set `Content type` to `application/json` when calling your API ?

Comment: Yes I did.I think the problem might be associated with the Student Class as ID is AutoIncremented.I was inserting the ID before and it was working fine.

Comment: Also check your insert query string concatenation, I think there shoud be a space between `)` and `VALUES`.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your rest call is not even reaching the jdbc part as there is problem in your rest request. I believe you are not setting the content-type properly. Try making below changes and see.

When sending the request please set `'Content-Type'` header property to `'application/json'`

and enhance your below handler method what is consumes.

```
@PostMapping(path="/NewStudent", consumes="application/json")
public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody StudentClass studentClass){
    studentService.addNewStudent(studentClass);
}
```

Try debugging your application. Your rest call should reach your above handler method.

Comment: I tried this but it does not help.It was working before I made ID AutoIncrement.